# A complete metric space $X$, a closed subset $K$ of $X$ and a point $x\in X$ such that $d(x,y)>d(x,K)$ for all $y\in K$?

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a *complete* metric space $X$, a *closed* subset $K$ of $X$ and point $x\in X\setminus K$ such  that for all $y\in K$ we have $d(x,y)>d(x,K)$? Ie no point in $K$ minimizes the distance between $x$ and $K$.

The answer is obviously true when $X$ is not complete (take $X=[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ with $K=[-1/2,0)$ and $p=1/2$).

But what happens when $X$ is complete? I was thinking to come up with a counter example in some $L^p$ space but I couldn't get much out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not difficult to construct such a metric, provided you don't mine from finite-dimensional normed linear spaces (such sets will be boundedly compact, which will guarantee a minimiser for $d(x, K)$). For example, consider the natural numbers $\Bbb{N}$, and define the following metric:
$$d(m, n) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } m = n \\ 1 + \frac{1}{n} &\text{if } m = 0 \neq n \\ 1 + \frac{1}{m} & \text{if } n = 0 \neq m \\ 2 &\text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
Positive-definiteness is easy enough to see, as is symmetry. To prove triangle inequality, just note that $d(x, y) + d(y, z) \ge 2 \ge d(x, z)$, for all $x, y, z \in \Bbb{N}$ where $x \neq y$ and $y \neq z$.

Note also that $\Bbb{N}$ is discrete under $d$, and hence is complete.

Define $K = \Bbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. We have, for all $m \in K$, $d(0, m) = 1 + \frac{1}{m} \to 1$, hence $d(0, K) \le 1 < d(0, m)$ for all $m \in K$, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try $X=l^\infty$ [the space of all bounded squences, with sup norm].  Let $e_n, n=1,2,\dots$ be the standard unit vectors.  Let 
$K =  \left\{u_n : n = 1,2,3,\dots\right\}$, where
$$
u_n:=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)e_n .
$$
So
$$
d(0,K) = \inf_n \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1
$$
and for all $u_n \in K$, $\|0-u_n\| > 1$.
Show $K$ is closed:  If $m < n$ then
$$
\|u_n-u_m\| = \max\left\{1-\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{m}\right\} > 1
$$
so sequence $(u_n)$ has no Cauchy subsequence, and thus no convergent subsequence.